# Why can't I call a function from my custom library?

Tags: java

I made a library in java to make calling maps from google maps easier and faster but I can't seem to import the jar file correctly. I followed the answer I found on this page [How to create my own java library(API)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612567/how-to-create-my-own-java-libraryapi) but it seems I am still doing something wrong.

I named the package in the library com.googleMaps and then I exported the .jar file and then added that .jar file into my build path of another project. I then made a class, imported `com.googleMaps.StaticMap;` Which gave me an unused library warning. Finally inside my main method I called `DisplayMaps("string");` which is a method inside of `StaticMap;` But it gives me an error saying the Method does not exist but the unused warning on the import went away.

Error is: The method DisplayMap(String) is undefined for the type MapTest1

Code:

```
import com.googleMap.StaticMap;

public class MapTest1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DisplayMap("A Url Goes here"); // This is where im getting the error
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see code and an error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call it with `StaticMap.DisplayMap("A Url Goes here");`. That's assuming it's a static method.

When calling a static method, you have to specify the class it belongs to, unless you are calling it from another method of the same class.

If it's not a static method, you have to create an instance of `StaticMap` before calling the method :

```
StaticMap map = new StaticMap(); 
map.DisplayMap("A Url Goes here");
```

Comment: I didn't realize they had to be static. Ill edit my code and see if that works.

Comment: @Ardel The method doesn't have to be static. But if it's not static, you'll have to create an instance of StaticMap before calling the method - `StaticMap map = new StaticMap(); map.DisplayMap(...);`

Comment: Ah ok I see that would work out much much better for me