# Externally store tools in Java project

Tags: java

I've written the following code to solve problem 1 which is to simply calculate the total of all multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000. (I realize I don't need the constructor, I just included it for practice).

```
public class p1multiplesOf3and5 {

public p1multiplesOf3and5() {
    //Constructor

}

public int sumArray(int[] Array){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int item: Array) {
        sum += item;
    }
    return sum;
}

public int sumMultiples3and5(int limit) {

    int[] multiples = new int[limit];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=1; i<limit; i++){
        if (i%3==0 || i%5==0) {
            count++;
            multiples[count] = i;
        }
    }

    int total = sumArray(multiples);

    return total;


}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    p1multiplesOf3and5 x = new p1multiplesOf3and5();

    int t = x.sumMultiples3and5(1000);

    System.out.println("Total is: " + t);



}

}
```

My question is based around the sumArray method I created and used. I have a background using MATLAB, and in some projects I've created a +tools folder for example, and would save this as a function within that folder. Any time I wanted to use it I could write tools.sumArray() to call it.

Is there a similar process for this in Java? As I feel this is a method I might use elsewhere and could be useful to have easy access to it, and any others I create.

Comment: Maybe a Java Library is what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612567/how-to-create-my-own-java-libraryapi

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, 1000).filter(i -> i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0).sum();`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko be aware the that project-euler tag was [burned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler). I also removed the [static] tag; tags should be what the question is _about_, not what it _contains_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to create a utility class which contains sumArray(). If you're using it within one project only, you can create a class called Utils and add a static method that does:

```
public class Utils {

    public static int sumArray(int[] Array){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int item: Array) {
            sum += item;
        }
        return sum;
    }  

}
```

so that you can use it later on in the following way:

```
int[] myArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
int sum = Utils.sumArray(myArray);
```

But the jdk 8 already has something like that, so you could avoid re-inventing the wheel:

```
Arrays.stream(myArray).sum();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, thanks. I did think such a simple method must already exist, it was more about the practice of creating it and trying to figure out how to call it as a function later on. Thanks for you help and for responding so quickly!