# Why do I have unresolved symbols that should be in my jar library?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

Gradle v2.9 (old I know, but upgrading is another project)

I see [How to create my own java library(API)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612567/how-to-create-my-own-java-libraryapi) and I'm doing something similar.

I'm pretty familiar with JARs and compiling Java code. I also have Maven experience, and I'm trying to do this in Gradle, but the fundamentals should be the same.

I want to create a library, which includes other libraries. So I have this `build.gradle` file

```
myLib/build.gradle:
dependencies {
  compile "com.someDomain:other-lib:1.0.0"
}
```

I can build `myLib-1.1.0.jar` with no issues, and deploy it to my repo as

```
artifactId: myLib
groupId: com.myDomain
version: 1.1.0
```

Now I want to use `myLib.jar` to build another component, `myComp.war`, so I have this

```
myComp/build.gradle:
dependencies {
  compile "com.myDomain:myLib:1.1.0"
}
```

So my dependency tree is as follows, meaning, `myComp` uses the `myLib` library, which in turn uses the `other-lib` library. Straight-forward enough.

```
com.myDomain:myComp:1.2.0
+--- com.myDomain:myLib:1.1.0
|    +--- com.someDomain:other-lib:1.0.0  <---- the symbol is in this library
```

and when I run `./gradlew build` for `myComp` I see both the `myLib-1.1.0.jar` and `other-lib-1.0.0.jar` artifacts being downloaded from my central repo, and stored in my `~/.gradle` cache. However, I get an `symbol not found` error for a symbol that's in `other-lib.jar` which was included in the `myLib.jar` file. Makes sense?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because building a jar only archives the files in that project's source tree, it does NOT include jars that it depends on for compilation. To package other jars within a jar, like I want to do, follow [How to include dependencies in a jar?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-dependencies-in-jar/19571/5) from the Gradle forum.